# How to call an async function in componentDidMount function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to fetch some Data from an API and put them in a flatList. Each row in the flatList has a white star button which when pressing it would make this entry added to the favorites that are saved in AsyncStorage. What I want to do is to get the keys that are saved locally and check whether this item is in the favorites list I want to show a black star. I am not able to fill the favorites array in the state.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage,
    Image, ToastAndroid, TouchableOpacity, FlatList
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoadingData: true,
            dataSourceEmpty: null,
            favorites: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('http://barcelonaapi.marcpous.com/bicing/stations.json')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((JsonResponse) => {

                this.setState({
                    isLoadingData: false,
                    dataSourceEmpty: JsonResponse.data.bici,
                    favorites: null
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    _touchListener = (item) => {
        alert("ID is:" + item.id + "\n"
            + "Latitude is: " + item.lat + "\n"
            + "Longitude is:" + item.lon)
    };

    makeFavorite(item) {
        this.saveData(item);
        ToastAndroid.show(
            'This station has been added to favorites!',
            ToastAndroid.SHORT
        );
    }

    saveData(station) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(station.id + "", station.name);
    }

    DATABASE_getAllBusStations = () => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                let keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
                resolve(keys)
            } catch (error) {
                reject(new Error('Error getting keys from AsyncStorage: ' +
                    error.message))
            }
        });
    }

    checkifInDatabase = async () => {
        try {
            var keys = await this.DATABASE_getAllBusStations();
            this.setState({
                isLoadingData: true,
                dataSourceEmpty: null,
                favorites: keys
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoadingData) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" animating />
                </View>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.header}>
                        BARCELONA BUS STATIONS
              </Text>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.dataSourceEmpty}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            let source = './Assets/fav.png';
                            // if(this.state.favorites.includes(item.id))
                            // {
                            //   source = './Assets/favblack.png';
                            // }
                            return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}
                                onPress={() => this._touchListener(item)}>
                                <View style={styles.row}>
                                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                                        {item.name}
                                    </Text>
                                    <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress=
                                            {() => this.makeFavorite(item)}>
                                            <Image
                                                source={require(source)}
                                                style={styles.imageStyle}
                                            />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        }
                        }
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    indicator: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    row:
    {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    item: {
        padding: 10,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#eee',
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
    },
    header:
    {
        backgroundColor: '#F03209',
        textAlign: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        color: 'skyblue',
        fontSize: 20
    },
    imageStyle:
    {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    },
    textStyle:
    {
        padding: 10
    }
});
```

Comment: don't return the result of the fetch call

Comment: what does it change

Comment: returning the fetch in componentDidMount serves no purpose but it shouldn't stop the call. I'm not able to tell where you're actually setting favorites. In componentDidMount, you're setting it to null again after the response.

Comment: I want to do this: componentDidMount() {
    this.checkifInDatabase();
    let keys = this.state.favorites;
    return fetch('http://barcelonaapi.marcpous.com/bicing/stations.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((JsonResponse) => {
      
        this.setState({
            isLoadingData:false,
            dataSourceEmpty: JsonResponse.data.bici,
            favorites: keys
        })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either nest your calls or move them to an async function. See my example below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ITestComponentState {
    message_1: string;
    message_2: string;
    message_3: string;
    message_4: string;
}

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, ITestComponentState> {
    renders = 0;
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message_1: null,
            message_2: null,
            message_3: null,
            message_4: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        /**Using nested fetch calls**/
        fetch('api/Local/GetData')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(message_1 => {
                fetch('api/Local/GetData')
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(message_2 => {
                        this.setState({ message_1, message_2 });
                    });
            });

        /**Using an async function**/
        this.getMessages().then((messages: string[]) => this.setState({ message_3: messages[0], message_4: messages[1] }));
    }

    async getMessages() {
        let message_3 = await fetch('api/Local/GetData').then(response => response.text());
        let message_4 = await fetch('api/Local/GetData').then(response => response.text());
        return [message_3, message_4];
    }

    public render() {
        const { message_1, message_2, message_3, message_4 } = this.state;
        this.renders++;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="test">Message 1: {message_1}</h1>
                <h1 className="test">Message 2: {message_2}</h1>
                <h1 className="test">Message 3: {message_3}</h1>
                <h1 className="test">Message 4: {message_4}</h1>
                <h2 className="test">Renders: {this.renders}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This one nests a fetch inside the first fetch.

```
        fetch('api/Local/GetData')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(message_1 => {
                fetch('api/Local/GetData')
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(message_2 => {
                        this.setState({ message_1, message_2 });
                    });
            });
```

This one puts them in an async method and calls the method inside componentDidMount.

```
this.getMessages().then((messages: string[]) => this.setState({ message_3: messages[0], message_4: messages[1] }));
```

```
async getMessages() {
        let message_3 = await fetch('api/Local/GetData').then(response => response.text());
        let message_4 = await fetch('api/Local/GetData').then(response => response.text());
        return [message_3, message_4];
    }
```

the results are:

```
Message 1: "Hello World!"
Message 2: "Hello World!"
Message 3: "Hello World!"
Message 4: "Hello World!"
Renders: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

what about making the `componentDidMount` itself async?

```
async componentDidMount() {
   try{
      const response = await axios.get('http://barcelonaapi.marcpous.com/bicing/stations.json')
      if(response.data.success){
         this.setState({
            isLoadingData: false,
            dataSourceEmpty: response.data.bici,
            favorites: null
      })
   }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
   }
}
```