# How return url for a img tag with a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

so I'm rendering out an array of posts. Each post has a unique user id associated with it, which I'm trying to use in another API call to return the user's image for that post.

Currently i have it setup like so

Rendering out the post

```
             {data?.map((data) => (
                <div className="allpostsingle" key={data.id} onClick={() => sendTo(data.id)}>
                    <div className="allpostheader">
                        <img src={getUrl(data.user)}/>
                        <p>{data?.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```

The function to get the image URL

```
   const getUrl = async (id) => {
       let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/${id}/`
       const response = await fetch(url)
       const data = await response.json()
       const avatarurl = data.avatar
       return avatarurl
   }
```

The issue with this is it returns a promise instead of the URL. I know you can set it in a state to get the url, but then it wouldnt be unique to each post?

Im just wondering how i can solve this or if theres a different way to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to call getUrl method getUrl()

Comment: its not a good idea to fetch each user data separately, instead you can get all users data in one request and then render it

Comment: what is the format of data.avatar? is it url or base64 encoded image data?

Comment: You have to include user data to posts data in the backend if it's possible I think

Comment: @HDM91 its a url to an image stored in an S3 bucket

Comment: this isn't possible to get all post data with users included ? if its not , you just need to get all users data with promiss.all in useEffect after that you get post data

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because rendering in react in synchronous while your `getUrl` is an async function. As some other answers pointed out, you can fetch all url in `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` hook and update the state.

If you don't want to change your existing code, you can also replace `img` with a react component of your own so it can handle promise.

```
function Image({src}){
  const [actualSrc, setActualSrc] = useState('placeholder image link')
  useEffect(()=>{
    src.then((url) => setActualSrc(url));
  }, [src]);
  
  return <img src={actualSrc}/>
}
```

```
{data?.map((data) => (
  <div className="allpostsingle" key={data.id} onClick={() => sendTo(data.id)}>
    <div className="allpostheader">
      <Image src={getUrl(data.user)}/>
      <p>{data?.description}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

```js
const getUrl = async (id) => {
       let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/${id}/`
       const response = await fetch(url)
       const data = await response.json()
       const avatarurl = data.avatar
       return avatarurl
}
```

This may not be best for performance as `getUrl` will send a new reference of promise on each render. In this case, best would be to pass `id` (user id in `getUrl`) to the `Image` component instead of a promise and have logic of fetching the actualUrl inside of it.

```
function Image({userId}){
  const [actualSrc, setActualSrc] = useState('placeholder image link')
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getUrl = async (id) => {
       let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/${id}/`
       const response = await fetch(url)
       const data = await response.json()
       const avatarurl = data.avatar
       return avatarurl;

    getUrl(userId).then((url) => setActualSrc(url));
  }, [userId]);
  
  return <img src={actualSrc}/>
}
```

```
{data?.map((data) => (
  <div className="allpostsingle" key={data.id} onClick={() => sendTo(data.id)}>
    <div className="allpostheader">
      <Image userId={data.user} />
      <p>{data?.description}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Would it help if `getUrl` was created via `useCallback()` with a dependency on `data`?

Comment: No, `useCallback` is to memoize the function reference, not the returned value.

Comment: Ah right. `useCallback` is still one of those grey areas for me where I never quite know when you'd use it

Comment: In this case, best would be to pass `id` (user id in `getUrl`) to the `Image` component instead of a promise and have logic of fetching the actualUrl inside of it

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign the return value of `getUrl()` to the `src` attribute because it is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`.

What you can do instead is maintain another piece of state for the user avatars that updates when your `data` does. For example, create a function that resolves user avatars

```js
const resolveUserAvatars = async (users) => {
  const avatars = await Promise.allSettled(users.map(async ({ user }) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/${encodeURIComponent(user)}/`)
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(res.status)
    }

    return {
      user,
      avatar: (await res.json()).avatar
    }
  }))

  return Object.fromEntries(
    avatars
      .filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled")
      .map(({ value: { user, avatar } }) => [ user, avatar ])
    )
  )
}
```

Then in your component...

```js
const [ data, setData ] = useState([]) // init as an array
const [ avatars, setAvatars ] = useState({})
// avatars will look like
// { userId: imageUrl, ... }

useEffect(() => {
  resolveUserAvatars.then(setAvatars)
}, [ data ]) // execute when data changes
```

and in your JSX

```
{data.map(({ id, user, description }) => (
  <div className="allpostsingle" key={id} onClick={() => sendTo(id)}>
    <div className="allpostheader">
      <img src={avatars[user] ?? "some/placeholder.png"}/>
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
))}
```

See also [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to get each user's avatar separately and send request for each post and every time render post items, If it's possible for you and the backend api just include users avatar url in post so easily render it.
if its not possible and have a limitation in api you just need to get all post user data with Promiss.allSettled in useEffect **after the post data has recieved** and attach user data  to postItem or keep it in separate dictionary then set the state to render the post and user avatar url in it.

Answer (score -1):

As you have said that your function returns a promise instead of URL (I had the same issue). This issue can happen to any asynchronous function when they are called as usual function (they will return a promise instead of an output), unless you use callback functions or async/await functions in a usual JavaScript code. But the in React, asynchronous functions should be called using `UsEffect()` hook OR `componentDidMount()` function. You need to refer to [How to call an async function inside a UseEffect() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838392/how-to-call-an-async-function-inside-a-useeffect-in-react) if your react component is a function. Or refer [How to call an async function in componentDidMount function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761900/how-to-call-an-async-function-in-componentdidmount-function) if your react component is a class to know how exactly use them in react to handle asynchronous functions in React components.